# Asana API - how to get incomplete tasks only?

Tags: asana

How do I get a list of tasks from a project that are incomplete? I tried to add `?completed=false` and `?completed=0` at the end of the tasks URL:

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/[project id]/tasks?completed=false
```

... doesn't seem to work. Whether its set to true or false, it is always returning the same tasks. I've spot checked to make sure there are completed tasks in there.

background info: I'm only trying to do this so that I don't get the entire list of tasks all the time. I need the entire list of tasks because right now as I understand it there is no way to get the section a task is in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Under "Querying for Tasks" in the [Developer Documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tasks) you'll find the parameters you can pass to select different tasks. We don't support generalized queries (like `completed=false`) but we do have e.g. `completed_since`, which returns all "incomplete or completed since X" tasks. So, if you *only* want incomplete tasks, you can pass `completed_since=now` (since no completed tasks have been completed since the current time, it will only return incomplete tasks). It's not exactly intuitive, but it works :-)

Comment: Dude the API is still responding with all the task, not only the incompleted once..
Already tried with "now" or writing down the exact current date-time formatted as it should.
But still..

Comment: Hmm, for me e.g. `GET /projects/#/tasks?completed_since=now` only returns incomplete tasks. Can you include the exact path you're requesting?

Comment: completed_since=now doesn't work any more since asana remove .id and using .gid