# How to get incomplete task using asana API in PHP

Tags: php, asana-api

I have to fetch only incomplete task using Asana API

```
$projectId = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
$args =  array('completed_since' => now);
$tasks = $asana->getProjectTasks($projectId, $args);    

$tasksJson = json_decode($tasks);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($tasksJson);
```

This code fetch all tasks (completed & incompleted tasks) related to that projectId. But I want to fetch seperate incomplete & completed task.

Comment: Have you read the ASANA API Doc?

Comment: Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613230/asana-api-how-to-get-incomplete-tasks-only

Comment: Yes, I got incomplete task of project. But it displays section tasks also. I dont want to show sections tasks? Please anyone have idea?